# Using lens for access to a Data.Sequence.Seq

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Is there any way to use `lens` to get functionality similar to the functions in `Data.List`?  For instance I am thinking of something like

```
isPrefixOf :: Eq a => Seq a -> Seq a -> Bool
isSuffixOf :: Eq a => Seq a -> Seq a -> Bool
```

And of course these functions would work on a list, vector, etc.  I would think `lens` could do this sort of thing but from the Haddocks it's not apparent to me.

Comment: There's really no need for lenses for `isPrefixOf` or `isSuffixOf`. Just use `splitAt` followed by `==`. Or use the package danidiaz suggested, which does exactly this.

Comment: @dfeuer - I presume you mean Data.Sequence.splitAt.  That's not polymorphic, which is part of the point of `lens`.  Even if it were, it's no direct substitute for `isSuffixOf`.

Comment: For `isPrefixOf`, you could certainly use a `Getter` (or maybe a `Fold`?) to convert to lists and then use `isPrefixOf` directly. But for `isSuffixOf`, that will carry a potentially serious penalty.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a lens-based answer, but the [monoid-subclasses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-subclasses-0.4.1.2/docs/Data-Monoid-Cancellative.html) package has the [RightReductiveMonoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-subclasses-0.4.1.2/docs/Data-Monoid-Cancellative.html#t:RightReductiveMonoid) typeclass that offers `isSuffixOf`, and [LeftReductiveMonoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-subclasses-0.4.1.2/docs/Data-Monoid-Cancellative.html#t:LeftReductiveMonoid) that offers `isPrefixOf`.

List and Seq (along with many other containers) are instances of those typeclasses.